# Rails: uninitialized constant after new installation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Are there any common causes of an an uninitialized constant error after a new installation?

```
uninitialized constant Activity
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
```

Everything's installed and migrated. I cheated by exporting the SQL and importing it into the new installation, where a couple of errors occurred but I can't think of why I'd get this error. The `activities` table exists in the DB, but I get that error both in the console and in the app itself.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Renaming the controller and removing the `public_activity` gem still gives me the same error. I'm beginning to think that cancan is not well set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a poorly configured cancan gem causing the conflict.

Comment: Nice :) I give you the solution, then you write and accept you own answer saying the same thing... funny practice

Answer (score 0):

Did you install cancan? Activity class is typical of this gem, and you can try to look in this direction.

Also `uninitialized constant` error could mean that the file name where is declared your class or module is incorrect.

Comment: Cancan is installed, yeah. `Activity` is the app's `public_activity` page.